# angular ngrx throwing error while trying to implement action reducer

Tags: html, css, angular

counter.actions.ts

```
    import { createAction } from "@ngrx/store";

export const increment = createAction('[Counter Component] Increment');
export const decrement = createAction('[Counter Component] Decrement');
export const reset = createAction('[Counter Component] Reset');
```

counter.reducer.ts

```
  import { createReducer, on } from "@ngrx/store";
import { increment, decrement,  reset } from "./counter.actions";

export const initialState = 0;

const _counterReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(increment, (state) => state + 1),
    on(decrement, (state) => state - 1),
    on(reset, (state) => 0)
);

export function counterReducer(state, action) {
    return _counterReducer(state, action);
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { counterReducer } from "./counter.reducer";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ count: counterReducer })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

output
16     StoreModule.forRoot({ count: counterReducer })
~~~~~
Error: src/app/app.module.ts:16:27 - error TS2322: Type '(state: number, action: Action) => number' is not assignable to type 'ActionReducer<number, Action>'.
Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.

```
    16     StoreModule.forRoot({ count: counterReducer })
                                 ~~~~~
        Error: src/app/counter.reducer.ts:14:32 - error TS7006: Parameter 'state' implicitly has an 'any' type.
        
        14 export function counterReducer(state, action) {
                                          ~~~~~
        src/app/counter.reducer.ts:14:39 - error TS7006: Parameter 'action' implicitly has an 'any' type.
        
        14 export function counterReducer(state, action) {
```

Comment: initialState = {count: number}. And in reducer: state.count + 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this just fix your initial state

```
const _counterReducer = createReducer(
    // initialize it
    initialState = {count: number} ,

    // your accessor need to access the values inside the state
    on(increment, (state) =>  parseInt(state.count)++),
    on(decrement, (state) =>  parseInt(state.count)--),
    on(reset, (parseInt(state.count)) => 0)
);
```